# unable to complete the test transaction, using Store Kit frame work (wrapped in c++) and a test user account

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, storekit

I just set up in app purchase for my game using the StoreKit ,wrapped in c++. When I purchase a product in my game, 
it asks for the iTune credentials. I put my test user accounts credentials. Then it tells , that its Sandbox environment and asks to tap buy. On tapping buy , it redirects to the iTunes, there again it asks for the credentials , I again fill the info and it further tells this is sandbox environment , I touch continue , then it either says "Cannot connect to iTunes" or prompts for the credentials again.

Also on tapping buy , first time , the transaction fails, logging the message to the console. And its description says same thing "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Edit: While it shows this message , there is a pop up asking "Verification Required"....some text... [ Environment:Sandbox], Here I tap on "Continue". From here it redirects to iTunes.

I have already tried:

1. Signing out of the iTunes in my device.
2. Creating a new test account.[ for Indian store].
3. Uninstalling the app from the device and installing again.

Edit: I believe products are added correctly in the iTunes as I am fetching them from it and then displaying them, and there cost are correct.

But still no way! Does anyone knows what I might be missing.

Comment: Have you submitted the app at least once before?  I had similar problem, from memory (sorry was some time ago) I found I went too far setting up the test account, at which point I needed to submit the app and then do Developer Canceled as soon as I had done it.

Comment: No, I have not yet submitted the app.Any chances that I need to create a US account as I read in forum https://discussions.apple.com/message/22997665#22997665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that agent team was providing me invalid test account.They were creating the account and then trying to login to apple store to the buy something using this test account, which immediately invalidates the test account. So creating new test account and then not using it to login to app store solved the problem.